# Replacing terms in a sum according to a condition

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

If I have a generic expression such as

```
8 + 48*(Subscript[e,1])^2
    + 64*(Subscript[e,1])^3
      + 12*(Subscript[e,3])^6 
        + ... 
          + n*Subscript[e,j]^k + ...
```

I like to replace terms of the form `n*(Subscript[e,j])^k` with `n` if `Mod[k,2]==0`, otherwise with `n*(Subscript[e,j])`.

How can this be achieved?

EDIT:

If i have

```
Subscript[e, 5]*Subscript[e, 7]*Subscript[e, 4]*Subscript[e, 3]*Subscript[e, 4]*Subscript[e, k]*Subscript[e, j]
```

I would like to return `Subscript[e, U]` if `k != j` compared all products, the return value will `Subscript[e, l]`, any idea? Thx

Comment: can `k` be `1` or `0`?

Comment: @garej yes, If k == 1 n*Subscript[e,j] else n

Comment: Something like `expr /. n_. (t : Subscript[e, _])^k_. :> If[Mod[k, 2] == 0, n, n t]` ... Look up `_.`

Comment: @garej thanks;) I do some testing and let you know ;)

Comment: @garej 
Translate
but it works , do not understand how vulnerability incorporate it in the following statement :
IInterval /: (IInterval[a_, b_, k_])^n_ := 
 If[ Mod[n, 2] == 0, 
  IInterval[a^n, b^n, 
   k], (Expand[(ToEuiForm[IInterval[a, b, k]])^n]) /. 
   n_. (t : Subscript[e, _])^k_ :> If[Mod[k, 2] == 0, n, n t]] .
http://s29.postimg.org/6a23qg3rr/sss.png
returns error, any idea?

Comment: Fixed up the formatting of the post, feel free to roll back if I've distorted your original intent.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I can infer a general rule from your edit. If I understand correctly, you want to return `Subscript[e, U]` if all the indices in the product are different, and `Subscript[e, l]` if not?

Comment: LLlAMnYP,Exactly, in general the term can be (Subscript[e, j])^k and follow the previous rule. Thx

Comment: No, the previous rule will ensure, that there are no repeated indices, you'll then always get the output with index `U`. But otherwise, if you have repetition of indices, MMA will transform the expression to one, where some subscripts will be to a power of greater than 1. If that's the case, then it's simple to realize, the result is `e_l`

Comment: LLlAMnYP to do it as you were saying ?

Comment: `f[expr_] := 
 If[MatchQ[expr, Times[___, Power[Subscript[e, _], _]]], 
  Subscript[e, l], Subscript[e, U]]`

Comment: your added edit seems like a completely new question. (??). If so you should ask a new question.  As there are no exponents in that expression what is `k`?

Comment: Thx LLlAMnYP ;)

Answer (score 2):

This replacement rule appears to give the intended result:

```
Subscript[e, j_]^(k_) :> Subscript[e, j]^Mod[k, 2]

8 + 48*(Subscript[e,1])^2+ 64*(Subscript[e,1])^3 + 12*(Subscript[e,3])^6 /.
   Subscript[e, j_]^(k_) :> Subscript[e, j]^Mod[k, 2]
(* 68 + 64*Subscript[e, 1] *)
```

Comment: LLlAMnYP if I want to incorporate this rule in the statement that I wrote in my previous comment? Thanks

Comment: @plus91 Presumably, like so:
 `If[Mod[n, 2] == 0, 
IInterval[a^n, b^n, k],
(Expand[(ToEuiForm[IInterval[a, b, k]])^n] /. 
Subscript[e, j_]^(k1_) :> Subscript[e, j]^Mod[k1, 2])]`.
I replaced the pattern name `k_` with `k1_` to avoid shadowing (the nasty red highlighting), but it's impossible to tell for sure, without the definition of `ToEuiForm`

Comment: LLlAMnYP Great!

Comment: LLlAMnYP I edited a question cause of new similar problem I'm trying to solve ;)

Comment: @plus91 Your edit to your question formulated a second, completely separate question. This is known as "moving the goalpost" and it is frowned upon here. Instead, I would suggest that you ask an entirely different question on that second point.

Comment: Sorry MarcoB ;)